# OFDM complex symbols have dynamic phase shift after the fft-block & before the BPSK demodulator at the receiver ,

Tags: phase, ofdm, software-defined-radio, amplitude, compression

[image][image]I have transmitted and received an OFDM-signal using the same ADALM-Pluto-SDR's Tx/Rx Antenna.

I have used BPSK baseband modulation with symbol freq=312.5 KHz, L (length of ifft)=64, fsampling=fsym*L=20 MHz. I basically sent 4 OFDM-symbols, each symbol has 64 symbol-length(52 subchannels and 12 null-subcarriers). The cyclic prefix is 0.25% of the ifft length. I used a barker code with my signal for synchronization.

At the transmiiter, I have noticed that many symbols after the ifft-block are approaching to zero and spreading around!
After correcting the time delay and phase shift at the receiver, I have observed that my baseband complex symbols, after the fft-block at the receiver and before the BPSK-demodulator, have an obvious dynamic phase shift as you see below in the figure (18) and also in the constellation diagram. At this stage, I was supposed to get real values of +1s and -1s with imaginary parts equal to zero as I used BPSK baseband modulation. Instead I got rotating amplitudes of +1s and -1s.

My question is what is the cause of this problem and how can I solve it in matlab. I have tried to implement several algorithms after calculating the dynamic phase shift but all did not work.

I would highly appreciate your support.
[The complex symbols after fft-block at the Rx before the BPSK demodulator[image: ][1]]

enter image description here

[image: The complex symbols after fft-block at the Rx before the BPSK demodulator]

[image: The ideal complex modulated symbol after BPSK modulator at Tx]

Comment: You said you have corrected the phase shift, but in the next sentence notice random phase shift. So, your correction, however you did that (you don't tell us!) Is not sufficient

Comment: Have you tried to generate the OFDM symbols in a matlab Tx simulation, and create an OFDM Rx simulation to demod the Tx signal? That may be helpful before working with your device. Matlab can simulate Tx/Rx OFDM symbols, but working with your own simpler custom simulation may give you better insight.

Comment: You said "At the transmiiter, I have noticed that many symbols after the fft-block". Did you mean "At the receiver", or did you mean, "after the ifft block"? I am pretty sure you know from your explanation that OFDM Tx uses ifft and the Rx uses fft. BTW, which of the figures is figure (18)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Acyually, I have tested my code with matlab simulation it works fine both at tx and Rx. When I didplay the constellation diagram after the ifft block at the Tx, it shows that the symbols are spreading out towards the original but this is not a big isdue since the demodulator will retrieve the bits correctly at the Rx using only simulation.

Comment: The issue now is that when I transmit the ofdm signal with Adalm Pluto SDR, I  corrected the time delay, random phase shift and after the fft block at the Rx I got the complex symbols rotating with dynamic phase shift as shown in the second figure while in fact I should only get real values of +1 &-1 and imaginary of zero after the fft block since these +1s & -1s will be feeding into the BPSK demodulator to retrieve my original bits as shown in the last figure of BPSK modulator at the Tx. What is the cause of the issue in the second figure? How can it be solved?

Comment: I hope my explanation is clear now

Comment: "The signals are spreading out towards the receiver" This makes no sense. The symbols are in the frequency domain, the dispersion happens in time – that's the whole point of OFDM. I suspect you mean *samples* when you say *symbols*?

Comment: and again, you say "I correct the phase shift", but clearly you are not correcting the phase shift, as you notice yourself. You need to **actually** tell us what you do for phase correction if you want to help us with your phase correction!  I'm afraid your explanation now really still isn't clear :(

Comment: In order to clarify the idea my Tx/Rx block diagram is shown below:

Comment: As you can see from the in the block duagram and also in the picture before the last, the complex samples after fft block at the Receiver are not real values of +1 & -1s. Instead, these complex samples have some kind if phase shift which makes the real part rotate as well as the imaginary values (see the picture before the last).

Comment: The complex samples after the fft block should be only real values of +1&-1 before the are fed to the BPSK demodulator at the receiver. Why this issue occurs even though I have corrected the random phase shift of the received time domain ofdm signal by using the the method of fft transform and atan2() then use exp(1i*phase angel)....

Comment: Then I use ifft again and return the signal to freq domain and go further at the block diagram. The phase shift I have corrected was at stage no. 10 in the blick diagram. The ussue niw occurs at stage 13. Can you please explain why and how I can equalize this issue to be the same as in the last picture

Comment: @AmrNasser wrote: "I corrected the time delay, random phase shift and after the fft block at the Rx I got the complex symbols rotating with dynamic phase shift".
- I do not see where you are correcting for CFO. Draw a figure of angle vs time (don't unwrap for good measure).

Comment: Have you tried using the SMA patch cable that comes with Pluto SDR to avoid the air gap to see what difference that may make.

Comment: My aim is to study the wireless channel, do estimation and equalization. What is CFO!The recent photo  shows the dynamic phase shift

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could suggest some solutions to this issue!

Comment: CFO is Carrier Frequency Offset. It is almost always present since the LO's of Tx and Rx are likely to have a small delta F difference.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think this is the effect of the wireless channel! Where the CFO is supposed to be corrected! in time domain or frequency domain!

Comment: No, CFO is the effect of the Rx LO not exactly matching the Tx LO, so even if you used an SMA patch to avoid the air gap, if Pluto SDR has two LOs for each antenna then the LOs are unlikely to be exact. When you see a nice arc like in your diagram, that is usually a sign of CFO that needs to be corrected. You can correct it in the time domain. The SMA patch cord should reduce other effects like multi-pathing, but that is off topic.

Comment: Although the SMA patch to avoid the air gap doesn't solve the CFO impairment, I recommend that you still use it to help get a cleaner receive signal which then becomes your baseline. You could also add the CFO impairment in your Matlab Tx/Rx simulation and then add OFDM CFO correction steps in the Rx.